# how to input in multiple lines in Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x

```
payroll = eval(input("Enter employee's name:""\nEnter number of hours worked this week:""\nEnter hourly pay rate:""\nEnter federal tax withholding rate:""\nEnter state tax witholding rate:"))

Enter employee's name:
Enter number of hours worked this week:
Enter hourly pay rate:
Enter federal tax withholding rate:
Enter state tax witholding rate:
```

I'm only able to input a value to the last line

Comment: Do multiple `input`s?

Comment: and I'd suggest not `eval()`ing the response.  you're telling the computer that you completely trust whatever the user input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want multiple inputs, you need multiple calls to `input`. Also avoid using `eval` unless you know exactly what you're doing; instead convert the input to the required type, like `float` for rates.

```
name = input("Enter employee's name: ")
hours = float(input("Enter number of hours worked this week: "))
rate = float(input("Enter hourly pay rate: "))
tax_federal = float(input("Enter federal tax withholding rate: "))
tax_state = float(input("Enter state tax witholding rate: "))
```

These var names are arbitrary - you can change them as you like.